# Bernays' phrase comparing sets/infinite to a piano extending in both directions

Tags: soft-question, math-history

I'm looking for a phrase that Bernays said about infinity. I remember it as "*Infinity is like a piano extending in both directions without end*", but I can't find it anywhere!

The most similar thing I found was:

"*Also in the grounding of analysis that starts by considering number sequences, the number series is conceived of as a closed, surveyable system, akin to an infinite piano keyboard.*"

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If I'm using the tags incorrectly please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it is a free translation of a sentence that we can find into :

- David Hilbert & Paul Bernays, [Grundlagen der Mathematik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grundlagen_der_Mathematik), Vol I (1934), page 17.

The [German text](https://books.google.it/books?id=z5KjBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA17) starting with : "Ähnlich verhält ..." (second paragraph) is translated as follows :

> It is much the same in every case in which a person thinks he can show
>   directly that some infinity is given in experience or intuition, for example the
>   *infinity of the tone series extending from octave to octave up to infinity*, or the
>   continuous infinite manifold involved in the passage from one color quality
>   to another. Closer consideration shows in every case that in fact no infinity
>   is given at all; rather it is interpolated or extrapolated through some mental
>   process.

Comment: I find it a little unlikely, but you may be correct